# I would like to know where is the `CurrentJDK/Classes` in java 8

Tags: java, macos, java-8, java-7

I want to iterate through all the *.jar files in this directory but these I don't see the folder in my mac machine, Please let me know if it's updated to a newer directory.

For java 7 - `System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK/Classes`

Comment: Try `which java` in your shell to identify where your java.exe is starting from. Alternatively, try to print `echo $JAVA_HOME`.

Comment: but where do I find all the classes directory?

Comment: Depends on the JVM implementation. In the `Oracle Jdk8`, it's in `$JAVA_HOME\jre\lib`; in the `OpenJDK11` it's `$JAVA_HOME\lib`